# How can I iterate through every possible combination of n playing cards

Tags: c++, playing-cards

How can I loop through all combinations of n playing cards in a standard deck of 52 cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need all combinations of `n` items from a set of `N` items (in your case, `N == 52`, but I'll keep the answer generic).

Each combination can be represented as an array of item indexes, `size_t item[n]`, such that:

- `0 <= item[i] < N`
- `item[i] < item[i+1]`, so that each combination is a unique subset.

Start with `item[i] = i`. Then to iterate to the next combination:

- If the final index can be incremented (i.e. `item[n-1] < N-1`), then do that.
- Otherwise, work backwards until you find an index that can be incremented, and still leave room for all the following indexes (i.e. `item[n-i] < N-i`). Increment that, then reset all the following indexes to the smallest possible values.
- If you can't find any index that you can increment (i.e. `item[0] == N-n`), then you're done.

In code, it might look something vaguely like this (untested):

```
void first_combination(size_t item[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        item[i] = i;
    }
}

bool next_combination(size_t item[], size_t n, size_t N)
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (item[n-i] < N-i) {
            ++item[n-i];
            for (size_t j = n-i+1; j < n; ++j) {
                item[j] = item[j-1] + 1;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It might be nice to make it more generic, and to look more like `std::next_permutation`, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

This combinations iterator class is derived from the previous answers posted here.

I did some benchmarks and it is a least 3x faster than any next_combination() function you would have used before.

I wrote the code in MetaTrader mql4 to do testing of triangular arbitrage trading in forex. I think you can port it easily to Java or C++.

```js
class CombinationsIterator
{
private:
 int input_array[];
 int index_array[];
 int m_indices;      // K
 int m_elements;     // N

public:
 CombinationsIterator(int &src_data[], int k)
 {
  m_indices = k;
  m_elements = ArraySize(src_data);
  ArrayCopy(input_array, src_data);
  ArrayResize(index_array, m_indices);

  // create initial combination (0..k-1)
  for (int i = 0; i < m_indices; i++)
  {
   index_array[i] = i;
  }
 }

 // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076695
 // bool next_combination(int &item[], int k, int N)
 bool advance()
 {
  int N = m_elements;
  for (int i = m_indices - 1; i >= 0; --i)
  {
   if (index_array[i] < --N)
   {
    ++index_array[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < m_indices; ++j)
    {
     index_array[j] = index_array[j - 1] + 1;
    }
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 void get(int &items[])
 {
  // fill items[] from input array
  for (int i = 0; i < m_indices; i++)
  {
   items[i] = input_array[index_array[i]];
  }
 }
};

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
// driver program to test above class

#define N 5
#define K 3

void OnStart()
{
 int x[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

 CombinationsIterator comboIt(x, K);

 int items[K];

 do
 {
  comboIt.get(items);

  printf("%s", ArrayToString(items));

 } while (comboIt.advance());

}
```

Output:

```js
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 2 5 
1 3 4 
1 3 5 
1 4 5 
2 3 4 
2 3 5 
2 4 5 
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class CombinationsIndexArray {
    vector<int> index_array;
    int last_index;
    public:
    CombinationsIndexArray(int number_of_things_to_choose_from, int number_of_things_to_choose_in_one_combination) {
        last_index = number_of_things_to_choose_from - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_things_to_choose_in_one_combination; i++) {
            index_array.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    int operator[](int i) {
        return index_array[i];
    }
    int size() {
        return index_array.size();
    }
    bool advance() {

        int i = index_array.size() - 1;
        if (index_array[i] < last_index) {
            index_array[i]++;
            return true;
        } else {
            while (i > 0 && index_array[i-1] == index_array[i]-1) {
                i--;
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                index_array[i-1]++;
                while (i < index_array.size()) {
                    index_array[i] = index_array[i-1]+1;
                    i++;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(5);
    int k = 3;
    CombinationsIndexArray combos(a.size(), k);
    do  {
        for (int i = 0; i < combos.size(); i++) {
            cout << a[combos[i]] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    } while (combos.advance());

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 2 5 
1 3 4 
1 3 5 
1 4 5 
2 3 4 
2 3 5 
2 4 5 
3 4 5
```

Comment: Despite some very clear variable names, this is just a wall of code without contextualization or comments and, as such, a poor answer.

Comment: I disagree with Richard. The use of  'very clear variable names' and code structure make comments unnecessary. Avoid comments that don't add value or improve understanding as they quickly get out of sync with the code. The solution is eminently readable and is a C++ implementation (as suggested by Amr Ali), which demonstrates use of the Standard Library too.

Answer (score -1):

I see this problem is essentially the same as the power set problem. Please see [Problems with writing powerset code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028670/problems-with-writing-powerset-code) to get an elegant solution.

Comment: Powerset enumerates all subsets of any size. But this wants subsets only of size n. This is a combinations problem, not a powerset problem.