# c++: next_combination with struct

Tags: c++, performance, combinations

Before I put my code, that I built it based on Thomas Draper code, and thanks to [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964837/n-choose-k-implementation-with-condition)

I will explain it in **example**:

```
Let this data in txt file: where each integer numbers associated with probability 
    1 0.933 2 0.865 3 0.919 4 0.726
    3 0.906 2 0.854 4 0.726
    4 0.865 3 0.933 5 0.919
Let the use input threshold = 1.5
```

I want to apply (next_combination) on my data in loop from k=1 until there is no more combination

**When k =1, the result will be:**

**First step:** generate all set of size 1, where the frequency of item can be represented by the summation of its probability.

```
{1}= 0.933
{2}= 0.865 + 0.854= 1.719
{3}= 0.919 + 0.906 + 0.933 = 2.758
{4}= 0.726 + 0.726 + 0.865 = 2.317
{5}= 0.919
```

**Second step:** ears all set of size 1, that has frequency of < threshold
==> We erased set {1}, {5}. And save the deleted item in another set

Repeat the steps when k=2

**First step: generate all set of size 2,**

We check to see if the generated set is superset from set that in erased set

we know that {1}, {5} already erased,
So no need to generate any superset include {1}, {5}

The rest generated superset will be:

```
{2,3} = (0.865 * 0.919 ) + (0.906 * 0.854) = 1.56774
{2,4}= (0.865 * 0.726) + (0.854 * 0.726)= 1.247994
{3,4}=  (0.919 * 0.726) + (0.906 * 0.726) + (0.865 *0.933)= 2.131995
```

**Second step:** ears all set of size 2, that has frequency of < threshold
==> We erased set {2,4} And save the deleted item in erased set, {1}, {5}, {2,4}

Repeat the steps when k=3 
From the previous step we only have: {2,3}, and {3,4} 
The new generated set will be

> {2,3,4} = (0.865 * 0.919 * 0.726) + (0.906 * 0.854 * 0.726)=
>   1.138846434 < threshold

I have done this code before with vector of vector of integer, it gives me correct answer but worst time. ([code](https://ideone.com/kWCzTM))

here where i need help, I got a lot of errors can't deal with them because i don't know how to employ next_combination with struct ([code](https://ideone.com/j1DOch))

Comment: Your compilation error with the second example is that you did not implement `operator<` for your struct.  You also include several headers you do not need including one that is deprecated causing other warning spam.

Comment: I add this code: `bool operator<(const Trans &a, const Trans &b)
{
 return a.Item < b.Item;
}` and it seems work, but still struggling with the performance/run time. thanks