# Problems with writing powerset code

Tags: c++, powerset

I'm trying to generate the powerset of a set and I wrote this code. The problem is, when user enter two similar member of the set it dosen't work properly. What can I do? 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

char obtain(char *p,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter member"<<(i+1)<<"\n";
        cin>>*(p+i);
    }
    return *p;
}

void set_display(char *p,int n)
{
    cout<<"{";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<*(p+i)<<",";
    }
    cout<<"}";
}

void powset(char *p,int n)
{
    unsigned int m = (double)pow((double)2, n);
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout<<"{";
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(i& (1<<j))
                cout<<*(p+j);
        }
        cout<<"}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unsure of what this has to do with C#, so i removed the C# tag.

Comment: Why the C language tag when you are using `cout` which is not defined in C or C#?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line was the error at?

Comment: it dosent have any errors but when i  compile the code to examine it  i enter one member twice and it didin't work correctly!

Comment: C++ have a very nice set of [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in the standard library, e.g. [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) which can be used to "transform" all members of a collection.

Comment: Also, _never_ mix `printf` and `std::cout`. Use one or the other.

Comment: Please add input, expected output and actual output to your question.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I understand why mixing `printf` and `cout` is probably indicative of sloppy coding, but why *never*? `sync_with_stdio` exists for a reason right? And for instance, a quick search says [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924530/mixing-cout-and-printf-for-faster-output) disagrees.

Comment: @BoBTFish The accepted answer in your linked question actually seem to suggest that if you skip using `std::endl` then `std::cout` is faster.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, but it does start by saying it is acceptable. I can't think of a reason you'ld want both to be honest (maybe you want to do something that is nicer with format strings, but don't want to do it into a buffer with `snprintf`...), but yours seemed to be more of a moral objection, the stress on *never* implying not just "I can't think of a good reason", but "There never can be a good reason". Maybe I just read too much into it.

Comment: is there anybody that can help me? i edited again but  it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I could not debug your code where you are missing. but since you posted your question I written an code in pure `C`. May be you find it helpful.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int N;
    char y[20]={0};
    int i,j;
    y[0] = 'a';
    y[1] = 'b';
    y[2] = 'c'; 
    N = 3;
    int powerSet;
    powerSet=pow(2,N);
    for(i = 0; i<(powerSet);i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            if((i & (1<<j))){
                printf("%c ",y[j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }           
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And its working:

```
:~$ gcc x.c -lm -Wall
:~$ ./a.out 

a 
b 
a b 
c 
a c 
b c 
a b c
```

**[ANSWER]**

You error case: When two symbols are same.

```
y[0] = 'a';
y[1] = 'a';
y[2] = 'c'; 

:~$ ./a.out 

a 
a 
a a 
c 
a c 
a c 
a a c
```

But this is wrong according to set theory. Because **in Set we can't have same element twice** (more then onec). BUT ALSO INPUT IS WRONG: `(a, a, c)` is not a set. So code is usable.

Comment: I written in `C` because you included not of header file with `.h` extention .

Comment: thanks alot so my code works too and it dosent have any errors